# Retrieving CommandLine arguments for processes owned by another user through WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)

Tags: windows, permissions, wmi, command-line-arguments, privileges

**Objective:**
As the title indicates, I would like to retrieve the command-line arguments of processes running on a Microsoft Windows server in the context of a monitoring tool.

Since the tool is used to monitor a critical system, there are some constraints (let's not argue about them, they can't be changed):

- The protocol used for monitoring has to be WMI.
- The monitoring tool has to use a dedicated user *mon-user*.

  - This user will under no circumstances get (complete) Admin rights on the machine; however specific, individual permissions might be granted if necessary.
- The tool shall retrieve the command-line arguments of (java)processes launched by **any user**, not only *mon-user*.

**Progress:** When I log on to the monitored system as *mon-user*, I am able to retrieve the process names and command-line arguments for processes launched by *mon-user* using the PowerShell command `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Select Name,CommandLine`. This shows the names for all processes (including those launched by other users) but only shows the command-line argument for processes launched by *mon-user* itself.

When I use the same command from the user account which launches the processes, I see the command-line arguments for processes of this user, but not for *mon-user*.

I do not have access to an admin account so I cannot verify if the admin is able to see the command-line arguments for processes launched by both users.

**Question:** From the observations above, I conclude that retrieving the command-line argument is linked to process-ownership (or admin rights as suggested by various other forum discussions). I would like to know, if there is some privilege, permission or user right that I could grant *mon-user* in order to get the required information.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: The process command line is a field in its process parameters. You need the right to read its virtual memory, i.e. `PROCESS_VM_READ`. This right generally isn't granted to a standard user by the discretionary access control list (DACL) of some other user's process. Moreover, if the process is elevated at high or system integrity with no read-up allowed, a standard-user process at medium integrity will also be denied read access. That said, an account with `SeDebugPrivilege` present and enabled is allowed to read the memory of most other processes -- except not *protected* processes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `SeDebugPrivilege` is an user privilege and can be given to a user and allows that user to debug (access & modify memory) any process; from a security point of view this would be equivalent to elevating that user to an admin (from a safety point of view it is not). On the other hand, `PROCESS_VM_READ` is an attribute specific to a process, so this can only be set once a process is running. The processes I want to monitor are launched from by a different process; can is it possible to grant the `PROCESS_VM_READ` right to *mon-user* when the child process is created?

Comment: `SeDebugPrivilege` is considered a 'super' privilege. If you grant this privilege to a standard user, a logon will be subject to UAC restrictions and normally require elevation to actually get `SeDebugPrivilege` in the access token -- unless you're using a service or scheduled task that can log the user on with "highest privileges".

Comment: Securable objects have a security descriptor (SD). This contains a discretionary access control list (DACL) and a system access control list (SACL, for auditing and mandatory control). The security descriptor can be set for a process when it's created via `CreateProcess`, or later by a process that's allowed to do so (i.e. has the `WRITE_DAC` standard right).

Comment: An ACL consists of access control entries (ACEs) that either allow or deny a set of rights to a particular security identity (e.g. user or group SID). Object rights are in a [32-bit access mask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374896). The lower 16 bits are for rights specific to an object type, such as `PROCESS_VM_READ`. The upper 16-bits are common for all objects. This includes standard rights such as `WRITE_DAC` and generic rights such as `GENERIC_WRITE`. Generic rights get mapped to a specific set of standard and object-specific rights depending on the object's generic mapping.

Comment: Here are the security rights for [Process objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880). For another example, here are the rights for [File objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258116).

Answer (score 2):

After some (administrative) effort I managed to work out a solution:
As part of the start-up of the processes I am interested in (my team has access to the source code), we implemented a change to the DACL by the process itself giving *mon-user* the additional permissions `PROCESS_VM_READ` and `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`.

Many thanks and a +1 to eryksun for the helpful comments.